# Error: Class 'Request' not found in Laravel config\azure-oath

Tags: laravel, azure-active-directory, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel-5.8 for a web application. In order to integrate Azure AD SSO, I installed this package in my application:

> composer require metrogistics/laravel-azure-ad-oauth

When, I wanted to relaunch my application I got this error:

> Class 'Request' not found

The error is found here:

config\azure-oath.php

[image: error screenshot]

How do I resolve this error?

Thank you

Comment: Try \Request::root()

Comment: @ImJT the same error is still there

Comment: Please see conversation regarding to this issue, https://github.com/metrogistics/laravel-azure-ad-oauth/issues/1 @mikefolu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved by the link in @Sunil kumawat 's comment, just add it as an answer to make it easier for others to find here.

https://github.com/metrogistics/laravel-azure-ad-oauth/issues/1

> I deleted that part of the code, now the code is like this: 'redirect' => '/ login / microsoft / callback', and it works for me.